# nonlinear equation

Tags: nonlinear-system

Is there any way other than symbolic tool, to solve for nonlinear set of equations in MATLAB without initial condition?
(Symbolic tool doesn't work or is very time consuming for very high order system of nonlinear equations)

Comment: It is better to use another CAS for solving systems of polynomial equations.

Comment: which CAS do you recommend other than symbolic?

Comment: Not MATLAB for symbolic, but GAP or SAGE.